# Deriving altitude from air pressure

Tags: pressure, temperature

I would like to infer altitude given air pressure. The problem is that the inferred altitude differs by a non negligible amount from the expected altitude, because I know exactly where the air pressure was measured.

Furthermore, I know the geography of where the measurements were taken. Can I use this to improve the accuracy of the inferred altitude? Perhaps the Temperature at altitude zero differs from country?

I used this equation
$$
\mathrm{z}=\frac{\mathrm{T}_{0}}{\mathrm{~L}}\left(\left(\frac{\mathrm{P}}{\mathrm{P}_{0}}\right)^{-\mathrm{L} \mathrm{R} / \mathrm{g}}-1\right)
$$

where $\mathrm{z}$ is the altitude, $T_0$ is temperature at zero altitude, $P_0$ is pressure at zero altitude and $P$ is measured pressure. The other are constant that I believe are irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SE Physics.  Could you perhaps write out Equation 8 from that link (rather than relying on the link) and provide predicted vs measured values to illustrate what you have done?

Comment: I can give you the difference between predicted and measured values. To be clear, measured : ground truth, predicted : inferred from equation. Predicted is below 50meters from measured across the whole time series.

Comment: Which datum and geoid are you using to define altitude?

Comment: i defined neither in my problem. rather i would like to know if there is any use to defining them?